# Create a Java Request in jMeter for validating multiple variables

Tags: java, jmeter

[image]

Here in My HTTP Request I extracted some variables using JSON Path Extractor. I want to create a Java Request it will validate the above variables. i.e I want to check the value of *reqVar1 is equal to resVar1 or not* and *reqVar2 is equal to resVar2 or not* like that.

Comment: can you please share the Java request and JSON Path? and also please clearly explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Naveen added Image and description for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things over complicated, you could achieve the same using normal [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

For example, if you have a JMeter Variable `${var1}` and you need to compare it to `${var2}`, `${var3}` and `${var4}` you can just configure the Response Assertion like:

[image: Response Assertion Example configuration]

More information on conditionally marking sampler results as successful or failed: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: If we use the above answer, it is same as adding 25 Response Assertions as he has 25 variables to compare. Response Assertions are not the answer either.

Comment: Dmitri, @Naveen is right, by going through your answer I need to write 25 Response Assertions. But I need to write a Request or any other available approach to make this process easy so that in future if I need to check more variables it will become easy to me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Java Request sampler, you can add [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) to compare the values. following is the code:

```
if(vars.get("reqVar1").equals(vars.get("resVar1")))
{
    if(vars.get("reqVar2").equals(vars.get("resVar2")))
    {
        SampleResult.setResponseCode("200");
        SampleResult.setResponseMessage("SUCESS");
    }
    else{
        SampleResult.setResponseCode("403"); // keep error code as per your wish
        SampleResult.setResponseMessage("reqVar2 and reqVar2 are NOT same" + vars.get("reqVar2") + vars.get("resVar2"));
    }
}
else{
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("403"); // keep error code as per your wish
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("reqVar1 and reqVar1 are NOT same" + vars.get("reqVar1") + vars.get("resVar1"));
}
```

Add the BeanShell Assertion as a child element to the HTTP Sampler in which you are getting the values for `reqVar1, reqVar2, resVar1, resVar2`

Once the decision is taken based on If condition, you can change the response code and message using `SampleResult`

Check the following reference that shows all methods available to you:

1. https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html

Image reference:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Initially I thought the same. But for some requests I need to compare 25 variables. At that time it is not an efficient way. So that I thought is there anyway to create a Java Request it will compare the values and return result.

Comment: can you please share how you are comparing the values using Java Request?  Unless you implement/extend Java Request, I don't think so, there is a way to compare the values (variables). please refer following answer on how to build your own Java Request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286893/how-to-write-a-jmeter-test-for-java-request

Comment: one more reference https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/creating-a-java-sampler-for-jmeter/

Comment: I gone through the provided links but I am unable to create a Java Request for my Requirements. Is there any better way to compare lot of variables. So that I am not going to write a BeanShell Code.