# Manually test grpc interfaces

Tags: soap, protocol-buffers, soapui, microservices, grpc

When you have soap webservice, you can always use soapui to create test xml requests for manual interface tests. You insert you test data into the xml document and send the request to the soap provider. You can then analyse the response in soapui.

We are currently thinking about switching from soap with xml to grpc with protobuf3. Is there a test gui for grpc that offers features as described above for grpc?

Comment: Use Jmeter and grpc-java, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018472/is-it-possible-to-use-jmeter-to-test-grpc

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the equivalent tooling is readily available, but we do continuously try to improve the state of tooling for gRPC and Protocol Buffers.

In the meantime, there is [grpc_cli](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md) project that might be immediately helpful, and gives you an idea if you want to build your own similar tool.

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://kreya.app, which is a gRPC GUI client, very similar to SoapUI for SOAP services (or Postman for REST services).

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Kreya.*

Comment: I was searching a simple and efficient gRPC and REST client, I tested several including the most known but was never satisfied for various reasons (forced to create online account, too heavy, weird bugs or restrictions)... I just tested Kreya, and so far I must admit I really really like it ! So thank you :). I will eventually think about paid version.